# IPython Failing to Run Code

Tags: ipython

I was trying out this Python code from [a training website](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/) in IPython:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = raw_input("www.google.com")

r  = requests.get("http://" +url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

and found that it ran fine on the first try.  I've now tried simply restarting the kernel, opening a new notebook, and generally returning the settings to how they were when I first ran the program with no luck.  Why might IPython be failing to run the code and giving no response at all (as though I haven't clicked anything)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `raw_input` is not supported by IPython. So it's probably just hanging there. If you change:

`url = raw_input("www.google.com")`

to

`url = "www.google.com"`

it should work.

Comment: When I try that I get an 'invalid syntax' error.  I'm also skeptical because it did work the first time for some reason with the bracket syntax.  Thanks though!

Comment: @MaxPower So you're saying on your first successful run it actually prompted you for input? The first argument to `raw_input` is the prompt text. So "www.google.com" doesn't really make much sense there.  Something like "Enter URL for link extraction:" would make more sense.

Comment: You're right.  I was completely misreading the code.  That was pretty silly.